# getting "fullscreenchange" post-event/post-reflow body dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to adjust canvas contents based on current screen dimensions. One annoyance I noticed with 'fullscreenchange' event is that `body`'s height/width seem to correspond to what they were prior to the event firing rather than after (or rather prior to the reflow). In other words, it's as if the event hasn't occurred yet when I'm trying to react to it by resizing the canvas element appropriately. Is there a way to use the dimensions that the `body` element would have after entering/exiting fullscreen finishes?

Here is my sample code:

```
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    console.log($body.width(), $body.height(), document.webkitFullscreenElement);
});
```

The element state (represented by `document.fullscreenElement`) seems to correspond to the post-event state, yet width/height do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I used `$(window).resize()` instead, which fires after the reflow.